# Unable to do changes on Google Fusion Tables (like insert, add table, etc.)

Tags: javascript, post, http-post, google-fusion-tables

I would like to write a small Google Chrome extension in which I use gooles fusion tables as a central data base.

Using existing tables and data (added via the GooleDoc-Webside) works quite fine (SELECT, SHOW TABLES, DESCRIBE) but if I try to do any changes (for this I need a "POST" request). I always get the following error: **"Missing sql parameter."** I have no Idea why this happens. I tried already alot (e.g. "create table test3(A:number,B:number)", insert .)

The code I wrote is the following:

```
function Fusion(readyCallback) {
    var myObject = {
        URL : "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query",
        authToken : null,
        doGET : function(command,callback) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("get"
                        ,this.URL+"?sql="+encodeURI(command)
                        ,true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization"
                                    ,"GoogleLogin auth=" + this.authToken);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { callback(xmlhttp.responseText); }
            xmlhttp.send();
        },
        doPOST : function(command,callback) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("post"
                        ,this.URL
                        ,true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization"
                                    ,"GoogleLogin auth=" + this.authToken);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { callback(xmlhttp.responseText); }
            xmlhttp.send("sql="+encodeURI(command));
        }
    }
    // client login authentification
    var email    = "XXX@gmail.com";
    var password = "XXX";
    var loginURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email="
              + encodeURI(email) + "&Passwd=" + encodeURIComponent(password) 
              + "&service=fusiontables&Source=testing";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("get",loginURL,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var tmp = xmlhttp.responseText;
        tmp = tmp.slice(tmp.search("Auth=") + 5, tmp.length);
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\n/g, "");
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\r/g, "");
        myObject.authToken = tmp;
        console.log("authentifiaction token status: "+xmlhttp.statusText);
        if (readyCallback) {
            readyCallback();
        }                                  
    };
    xmlhttp.send();

    return myObject;
}
```

If I for example try to do something like this

```
mf.doPOST("INSERT INTO 2664928(ID,Text,Number) VALUES (2,'Hallo',3)",mc)
```

or this

```
mf.doPOST("INSERT INTO 2664928(col4,col0,col1) VALUES (2,'Hallo',3)",mc)
```

with a table, described by this

```
column id,name,type
col4,ID,number
col0,Text,string
col1,Number,number
```

I keep getting this error (the same when I try to create a table)

Any suggestions? I am realy confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message about the "Missing sql parameter." seems not to be the real error.

When I correctly understood the issue, **it is currently not possible to POST data to Fusion Tables using JavaScript**. If GFT would send to appropriate CORS headers for POST requests, it could actually work. But this is not the case as of now.

See issue 554 (http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=554).

Comment: Note that in the meantime Google announced the _new_ API, which is available for Trusted Testers, to become one [join this group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fusion-tables-api-trusted-testers). There you can find examples and even a JavaScript client library.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a content-length header to the request:

```
var query = "sql="+encodeURI(command);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", query.length);
```

Also, I would recommend sending the ClientLogin request as a POST request rather than the GET request, so that the username and password are not sent as part of the URL.

Comment: Hi,
I changed the loign into a POST request and added the content-length (getting the "warning": Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length").
However, the behaviour keeps getting the same!
But thanks alot for your answer!